# Open Excel sheet in share point page/webpart itself

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In share point 2010, I would like to have an excel sheet(2007) in sharepoint site, where the Excel sheet should be displayed in the site itself (Possibly a webpart). 
**And the users should able to edit the excel sheet from webpart itself** (No need to open the Excel sheet in seperate MS Excel). I meant adding new rows of data and editing existing the rows.
I come across various posts regarding the above issue, [like this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/25/create-excel-web-access-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/).

How ever I am unable to get the category 'Office Client Applications' under insert webparts.
Please help me on this.
Can anyone please give me a suitable link or tips for achieving the above?
Many Thanks !!

UPDATE - Adding Error Info

"Excel Services is unable to process the request. Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again"

Comment: I got excel web access webpart, when I used a separate webpart page, How ever after I used it, I am getting an error like, "Excel Services is unable to process the request. Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again". Even if I directly access the excel from the document library also I am getting the same error, any thoughts? I want to show the Excel in webpart/page itself, do not want to activate the feature open in client option. Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end got it working, In order to get rid off the error we need to activate the **Excel services web service application proxy** in web application **service connections**.

In case the above mentioned proxy is not available under the service connections, go ahead and create one. Need some help, [its right here](http://www.stickyglue.co.za/index.php/archives/97/comment-page-1#comment-1921) !!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Action > Site Collections Features > Activate " SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features "

Then go to page & edit page > add web part.
Select "Business Data" Category & add "Excel Web Access" web part.

Its working my end.

Comment: Thank you friend, for that info, however after adding the webpart, I am getting an error like (see the comment under question) - "Excel Services is unable to process the request. Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again" Please help...